# Convert char to TCHAR* argv[]

Tags: visual-c++, argv, tchar

How can I input text into `TCHAR* argv[]`?

OR: How can I convert from `char` to `TCHAR* argv[]`?

```
char randcount[] = "Hello world";

TCHAR* argv[];

argv = convert(randcount);
```

Comment: TCHAR* argv[]=_T("HelloWorld");
 Its showing error

error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [134]' to 'TCHAR *[]'

Comment: You are missing " at the beginning :-) apart from the `TCHAR* argv[]` is an array of TCHAR pointers and you are trying to assign a string to it. You need to something like this: `TCHAR* argv[10]; argv[0]=_T("HelloWorld");`

Comment: i gave my code like this


     TCHAR* ptszFirstInFile  = _T("sample1.asf") ;
     TCHAR* ptszSecondInFile = _T("sample2.asf") ;
     TCHAR* ptszOutFile      = _T("xxxx.asf") ;

NOw getting error 

cannot convert from 'const char [12]' to 'TCHAR *'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do is:

```
char a[] = "Hello world";
USES_CONVERSION;
TCHAR* b = A2T(a);
```

Comment: #include "atlstr.h"

Answer (score 0):

/*This code did TCHAR in my project without A2T or any other converters. Char text is a some kind of array. So we can take letters one by one and put them to TCHAR. */

```
    #include <iostream>
   TCHAR* Converter(char* cha)    
   {
       int aa = strlen(cha);
       TCHAR* tmp = new TCHAR[aa+1];
       for(int i = 0; i< aa+1; i++)
          {
            tmp[i]=cha[i];
          }
       return tmp;
   }

   int main()
   {
       char* chstr= new char[100];
       chstr = "char string";
       TCHAR* Tstr = new TCHAR[100];
       //Below function "Converter" will do it
       Tstr = Converter(chstr);
       std::cout<<chstr<<std::endl;
       std::wcout<<Tstr<<std::endl;
   }
```

Comment: Can you please explain your code a bit so others can understand?

Comment: This code did TCHAR in my project without A2T or any other converters. Char text is a some kind of array. So we can take letters one by one and put them to TCHAR.

Comment: Can you put it in your answer, please?