# VS 2010 C++ - Conversion Errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, implicit-conversion

I wrote an app in C++, and downloaded some samples code from the internet (like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380536) and [this](http://www.coastrd.com/c-schannel-smtp)),
but when I try to compile the code I get compilation errors like:

> error C2664: 'CertNameToStrW' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'CHAR [1000]' to 'LPWSTR'
>
> error C2664: 'send' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'BYTE [200]' to 'const char *'

and so on.

Certainly, I can solve it by explicit conversion like suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652643/convert-char-to-tchar-argv) question.
but I want to ask if this behavior is reasonable? I assume that Microsoft guys compile their code before they upload it to MSDN. What do I miss? Maybe I have to install somthing? can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by having the wrong character set, see here:

http://www.ucancode.net/faq/Visual_c_character_sets-Unicode-MBCS.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off `Unicode` from your project settings `Project Properties -> General -> Project Defaults -> Character Set` or use win32 api functions with `A` postfix like `CertNameToStrA` instead of `CertNameToStr`.